# what is the best way to get time conflict in java ?

Tags: java

I am developing (time scheduler) application in java. i have list of objects, which contains start and end time in form of long. what is the best way to find out remain time other then in my list of object. so i can display free time in particular day.

my object Structure,

```
List <TimeObj>
    |-------Long startTime,
    |-------Long endTime,
```

Output

List of free time like 00:00 to 08:00, 10:00 to 11:00 (i can do conversion of time my self)

Comment: You mean to ask difference between `Start Time ` and `End Time` ?

Comment: Could you specify exactly what you mean with "remain time"?

Comment: what is the minimal unit considered (hours?), if so you could create a map hours=>boolean and iterate on your list and update the map

Comment: use the calendar class

Comment: Can't you use Joda Time? You'll have a much easier... Time... Doing what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to parse your question.  The one I'm answering is:

Given this timeline:

```
<---->     <-->     <------->  <>
```

Create this timeline ("remain time"):

```
      <--->    <-->          <>
```

My solution: stick with `long`s, don't convert to dates.  Sort the list of `TimeObj`s and create a new list of `TimeObj`s, where each new `TimeObj` is constructed from the `endTime` of one `TimeObj` to the `startTime` of the next `TimeObj`, so long as `startTime` > `endTime`.  That will give you a list of "remain time".

Comment: Thanx paul, i am starting with it. I already thought about that. thanks again.

Comment: Oh no need to thank me.  Upvotes and accepts are sufficient reward! ;)